# Exiting a function when it's done or after some specific time(Even it's not done) in java

Tags: java

I need to forcefully stop a method in java after some time if it's not finished yet.I implemented this with a while loop. But it waits throughout the whole time even the function execution is done.

If it's finished by this time,I need the loop to be stopped.
Any suggestions would be great.

EDITED FROM HERE

```
import java.util.concurrent.* ;

ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 ) ;
svc.submit( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myFunction();
  }
} ) ;
svc.shutdown() ;
svc.awaitTermination( 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

I tried this code. it worked ok. But when myfunction is done/exits due to time constraints, the code remain paused for some moment.I don't know why.:(

Comment: Let's have a look at what you already coded.

Comment: No I implemented it normally.                                             <code>while(System.currentTimeMillis() < specificTIme)
{
 hbsgsNoneObj.solve();
 
}</code>

Comment: No, what's wrong with that is that the time check only happens once before and once after `solve()` completes -- never during. What's worse, it will call `solve()` again if it completes before the time limit the first time.

Comment: You can't check the time on something in the same thread as it is executing. Those are two different operations. You need to have another thread counting time, then interrupting the thread that is calling your function. This is essentially what FutureTask does for you, as referenced in my answer.

Comment: can u check out the code i edited.. It'd be great if u can give me an example with future task .thanks!

Comment: I guess the above mentioned code keep running though it responds to svc.shutdown().

Answer (score 3):

Call your function from a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and use the get(long, TimeUnit) method. A TimeoutException will indicate that it timed out before finishing, otherwise you get the result of the function.